# convert models to json

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently I am working on a request that takes a database with the following class.

```
class Player(db.Model):
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... etc
```

... and then I am trying to return all players in JSON format with the following function

```
class Players(Resource):
    def get(self):
        result = Player.query.all()
        return result
```

However so far I have not been able to get my result in JSON format. With the above code I get an error reading

```
Object of type Player is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried things like...

```
final_result = result.json()
return final_result
```

or ...

```
final_result = json.dump(result)
return final_result
```

neither of these solutions have worked for me. My end goals is to return all players in JSON format to first postman, and then my front end client when I am done with this project.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json)

Comment: While that thread this one are similar they are not the same. In this instance I am trying to change a list into JSON format, and in that thread they are trying to change dict into json format. Those answers won't work here.

Comment: @DavidReke just use `jsonify(Players.query.all())` + [app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544630/proper-overloading-of-json-encoding-and-decoding-with-flask)